# ORDER BY desc in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table that has :

```
nb  | label 
60  | from 2 and less
25  | from 3 to 16
15  | from 17 to 100
```

I try to get the descending order so I use the query :

```
select * from table order by label desc;
```

But I don't get the right order, instead I have the following :

```
[ { nb: 25, label: 'from 3 to 16' },
  { nb: 60, label: 'from 2 and less' },
  { nb: 15, label: 'from 17 to 100' } ]
```

Does it consider 17 as 1 ? How can I get the right order?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Extract the number part and cast it to integer data type.

Comment: if you can put 0 infront of the 2 and 3 then it will sort the way you want.  strings sort based on the first character they encounter  so 3 is > 2 > 1  it doesn't see the 7 behind it.  The `from and space match` the first variance is the 3,2,1 and that's sorted correctly in a string.  add the 0 or cast the numbers to numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain.  The easiest is if you have another column that has the same ordering.  But assuming the second word is an integer that does not start with 0 and the first word is "from":

```
order by patindex('%[0-9] %', label) desc,
         left(label, patindex('%[0-9] %', label)) desc
```

This essentially finds the length of the first number and uses that for the first key in the `order by`.  Then it orders by the first number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this answer gives the ascending order , but when I put : 
order by patindex('%[0-9] %', label),
         left(label, patindex('%[0-9] %', label)) desc it doesn't work

Comment: @Jean . . . Both keys need `desc`.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix, just change it to:

```
                     ...from 03 to 16' },
      { nb: 60, label: 'from 02 and less' },
      { nb: 15, label: 'from 17 to 100' } ]
```

Or extra space instead of zero:

```
                     ...from  3 to 16' },
      { nb: 60, label: 'from  2 and less' },
      { nb: 15, label: 'from 17 to 100' } ]
```

Both should sort it the way you want.